# HW:Computing the PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

> Let $X$ be a continuous uniform random variable on the interval $[0,3]$ and $Y = 2 \cdot X − X^2$
>
> 1) Compute the pdf of $Y $
>
> 2)check that it is a pdf

My answer is $\frac{1}{6 \sqrt{1-y}} I[-8,1]$ and otherwise $0$. I am not sure if this is right but if anyone could let me know where I went wrong or if its right that would be appreciated.

- To calculate this used the quadratic formula and got
  $$G(y)=\Pr(1-\sqrt{1-y}< x<1+\sqrt{1-y})$$
- since the bounds for X are 0 to 3 i did $$\textbf I_{[0,1+\sqrt{1-y}]} f(x)=\frac13$$
- then I got my answer to be $$\frac13(1+\sqrt{1-y})$$
- From there i took the derivative and got the final answer shown above 
  -I got the bounds $-8$ to $1$ since $1$ is the highest value y could take and $-8$ since $x=-2$ gives you -8 when you do $Y=2(-2)-(-2)^2$

-Kinda new here so my apologies if its confusing

Comment: Do you mean $Y=2X-X^2$?

Comment: Sanity check gives $\int_{-8}^1 \frac{1}{6\cdot \sqrt{1-y}}\, dy=1$. That means, we cannot definitely say that your result is wrong. You should show what you have calculated.

Comment: I´ve made an edit. Your reasoning looks right to me. Nice work.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :)