# help finding the PDF of this function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function

the question I'm trying to solve is  let x be a continuous uniform random variable in the interval [0,3] with $$
y= 2x-x^2
$$
what I did so far is used the method of transformation, and solved for x using the quadratic formula getting, $$ 1\pm \sqrt{1-y}
$$
then finding the derivative I got $$
\pm \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}}
$$
combining everything together with the method of transformation formula: $$
f_x(f^{-1}(Y)) \frac{dh^{-1}}{dy} = \frac{1}{3}\left(\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}}\right)= \pm\frac{1}{6\sqrt{1-y}} ~\text{for}~ -3<y<0 
$$
i got the bounds by subsituing x with 0 and 3, but when i try proving this is a PDF by finding the integral from -3 to 0 i dont get 1, i get 1/3. but i realize if  i dont multiply 1/3 and just find the integral of the inverse function i do get 1 i.e the integral $$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}} 
$$ from -3 to 0 the answer is 1. any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint: Consider the range of $2x-x^2$ on $[0,3]$ by sketching it (find max/min, zeros)

Comment: Same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3652065/321264.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how they got -2 for x